# How to set up Tomcat to use the config file in conf/Catalina/localhost?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, configuration

so my question is how can I set up a Tomcat Server to use this configuration file conf/Catalina/localhost/MyApp.xml?

It works like a charm if my application is named like this: MyApp.war so tomcat will extract the archive to MyApp.
But I want to use a name with the version inside like MyApp##1.0-SNAPSHOT.war.
Is it possible to configure the tomcat so it will use the MyApp.xml anyway?

Answer (score 1):

With default tomcat installation if we keep $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/WAR_FILE_NAME.xml then it will be picked up when tomcat starts.
e.g (as per my practical use) I have 3 wars inside $CATALINA_BASE/webapps say

- myapp.war
- yourapp.war
- ourapp.war

So inline with these WARs I have kept following context xmls inside $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/ directory

- myapp.xml
- yourapp.xml
- ourapp.xml

These are picked default context xmls for its respective named WAR file.

note. I have used it in tomcat 9x

Answer (score 0):

You can set `path` and `docBase` attributes of Context element as described in the [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html).
Create a directory outside `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps` and place war files there, let's say `/opt/tomcat/wars/`. Then set `docBase`attribute to the full path to your war. Make user tomcat user has read permissions on that directory. If war is inside webapps directory you could end up with a double deployment depending on deployOnStartup and autoDeploy attributes of Host element.

```
<Context path="/MyApp" docBase="/opt/tomcat/wars/MyApp##1.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
...
</Context>
```

You can try also naming the xml the same as the war file.

Comment: but I don't want to 'hardcode' the name of the war file anywhere. If a new version lets say MyApp##1.1-SNAPSHOT.war is deployed I have to edit all the hardcoded lines.

Comment: I think you can use the `copyXML` attribute of the [Host element](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html) in server.xml. Then the xml name should follow the war name. In the default scenario the `WEB-INF/context.xml` will be copied to `conf/Catalina/localhost/` with the same base name as the war I guess. If you require the xml to be named `MyApp.xml` without versioning you will have to edit it each time the war version changes. Ant tasks can be used also to deploy but have not used them myself.